# How to add a specific listview row to another listview on another form

Tags: c#

If i select a listview row from my form1, I want "some" of the data in form1 row to be placed in form2 list view

Form 1 code:

```
private void StandardUserListView_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            ViewUserDetail vud = new ViewUserDetail(StandardUserListView.SelectedItems[0].SubItems[1].Text, StandardUserListView.SelectedItems[0].SubItems[2].Text, StandardUserListView.SelectedItems[0].SubItems[3].Text, StandardUserListView.SelectedItems[0].SubItems[4].Text);
            vud.ShowDialog();


        }
```

Form 2 code:

```
        public ViewUser vu;

private void ViewUserDetail_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ScheduleListView.Items[0].SubItems[0].Text = vu.StandardUserListView.SelectedItems[0].SubItems[0].Text.ToString();
            ScheduleListView.Items[0].SubItems[1].Text = vu.StandardUserListView.SelectedItems[0].SubItems[1].Text.ToString();

        }
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Add a public Property or Method to `ViewUser` that accepts a `List<string>` as value/argument. Then, for example, `ViewUserDetail vud = new ViewUserDetail(); vud.ThePublicMethod(aListOfStrings); vud.ShowDialog();`. In `ThePublicMethod()` method of `ViewUserDetail`, add to the ListView the strings you find in the list. `aListOfStrings` of course contains the elements of `Form1's StandardUserListView` you want to add to Form2's `ScheduleListView`. You could also use a class that handles the data exchange, so the two Forms can ignore each other, delegating the procedure to something else.

Comment: @Kevingy i have 6 columns on my listview, if i double click on that row it will go to another form that has another listview, but in that listview it will only display 3 columns instead of 6

Comment: @Jimi how will I do this? Im still new to this, your explanation is confusing :(